# create validation in add user page for php

Tags: php, validation

i have create a page to add user and i user "insert into" as my sql code, and i want to make validation to add the user, i mean it show the error if curtain column is empty when add user.. this my code

HTML page
adminadduser.html

```
<body>

<div>
<!--head-->
<div class= "kepala">
<a href="#"><span class="foundicon-smiley"></span></a>ADMIN

</div>

<div class= "content">



<div class="menu">
<div class="menu_box_list">
                <ul>
                    <li><a action="php/display_user.php" href="adminMuser.php"><span class="foundicon1-person"></span> Manage user <i class="manageuser">  </i><div class="clear"></div></a></li>
                    <li><a href="adminVehicle.php"><span> </span> vehicle manager <i class="vehicle manager"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="report1.php"><span class= "foundicon-page"></span>  report <i class="Report"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                    <li><a href="php/destroySession.php"><span class= "foundicon-settings"></span> log out<i class="settings"> </i><div class="clear"></div> </a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>




</div>



</div>
<div class="1st_menu">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="php/saveuser2.php">
<div class="table5">
 <font style="font-weight:bold">REGISTER USER</font>
 <ul>
        <p>
        Nama: <input type="text" name="name" />*
        <?php echo $name;?>
        </p>
        <p>
       Matric No: <input type="text" name="matric" />*
       <?php echo $matricErr;?>
        </p>
        <p>
        Password: <input type="text" name="pass" />*
        <?php echo $passErr;?>
        </p>
        <p>
        User Category: <select name="cat" id="user_category">
          <option>Staff</option>
          <option>Student</option>
          </select>*
          <?php echo $catErr;?>
        </p>
        <div class="buttn1">
        <p>
        <input name="add" type="submit" onClick="Adduser()" value="Add" />

        </p>
        </div>
    </ul>

</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class= "Bfooter">
<h4></h4>



</div>



</div>




</body>
```

and this my PHP file

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }



mysql_select_db("vronline", $con);

 $nameErr = $matricErr = $passErr = $catErr = "";
 $name = $matric = $pass = $cat = "";


$sql="INSERT INTO user_information(user_id, user_password, name, user_category)

VALUES

('$_POST[user_id]','$_POST[user_password]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[user_category]')";



if ($sql["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["user_id"])) {
     $matricErr = "Please insert matric no!";
   } else {
     $matric = $_POST[user_id];
   }

   if (empty($_POST["user_password"])) {
     $passErr = "Please insert password!";
   }else {
     $pass = $_POST[user_password];
   }

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $name = "Please insert name!";
   }else {
     $name = $_POST[name];
   }

   if (empty($_POST["user_category"])) {
     $catErr = "Please choose category";
   } else{
       $cat = $_POST[user_category];
       }


}
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

header("location:../adminMuser.php");



mysql_close($con)

?>

</body>

</html>
```

i cant make it work to show the error, which part i make it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach, to validate using `PHP`

```
session_start();
$is_valid = false;
$error = array();
if (empty($_POST["user_id"]) || !isset($_POST["user_id"])) {
    $error[] = "Please insert matric no!";
}

if (empty($_POST["user_password"]) || !isset($_POST["user_password"])) {
    $error[] = "Please insert password!";
}

if (empty($_POST["name"]) || !isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $error[] = "Please insert name";
}

if (empty($_POST["user_category"]) || !isset($_POST["user_category"])) {
    $error[] = "Please choose category";
}
$is_valid = (count($error) == 0);

if($is_valid){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234", "vronline");
    if (!$con){
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO user_information(user_id, user_password, name, user_category)
                  VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
                  $_POST['user_id'],$_POST['user_password'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['user_category']);

    mysql_query($sql,$con) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error();
    mysql_close($con)
    header("location:../adminMuser.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['errors'] = $error;
    //you can redirect back to the form to here
}
```

Then on your forms, you should check if the session is set, and print the errors if any:

```
session_start();
$errors = $_SESSION['errors'];
foreach($errors as $error){
    echo "<p> Error = ".$error."</p>";
}
```

---

**Please note:**

While validation using PHP required, but you should validate on the client side as well.

Good practice wants you to validate  using `javascript` or `jquery`.

It is a waste to send request to your server when they are not valid/complete.

Nowadays it is even easier with `HTML5` validation attributes.

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```